# Can not get a key with curses

Tags: python, python-3.x, listener, curses

I am trying to use curses to display some statistics, and I do face a problem.

I wanted to have a window which allow scrolling thanks to the keyboard. For this, I create a variable self.scroll, which tells me which lines I should display. The problem is that I want to increment this variable whenever I press KEY_DOWN.

Here is my code :
In the init of the class, I do have :

```
    self.stdscr = stdscr
    self.scroll = 0
    stdscr.nodelay(1)
    stdscr.keypad(1)
```

Then :

```
    while True:
        ch = self.stdscr.getch()
        if ch == curses.KEY_DOWN:
            self.scroll += 1
            self.add_alert()
            ch = None
        elif ch == curses.KEY_UP:
            if self.scroll >= 1:
                self.scroll -= 1
            self.add_alert()
            ch = None
```

I also used a wrapper that can be found [here](https://github.com/enthought/Python-2.7.3/blob/master/Lib/curses/wrapper.py) to initialize everything.

The fact is that the variable scroll is stuck at 0, no matter what. Moreover, I see every key that I press (e.g ^[[A) whenever I press it, even if noecho() is set.
I used nodelay(), because my thread is also processing some things, and I do not want it to be stopped while waiting for a key to be pressed.
Do you have any idea from where it could come ?

Thanks a lot,
Djaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it was working from the beginning. The problem was just that for some strange reasons, curses did not detect KEY_UP and KEY_DOWN. I just replaced them by u and d

```
if ch == ord('p'):
```

and everything is working fine.

Thanks to everyone !

Answer (score 0):

If you use `nodelay`, that interferes with `keypad`.  Use `timeout` with a short timeout value, instead.  (10 milliseconds for a timeout will work for most people).

Comment: Hello, and thanks a lot for this ! I do not know how I missed that in the doc.
Unfortunately, my variable does not increment. I do have several windows in my code, do I need to keypad(1) and timeout(10) all of them ?